# Mapbox Choropleth Maps not showing

Tags: python, json, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I am a fresh starter with Python for Data science and this is my first help request here (then apologize in advance for some mistakes). Need your support to get why this choropleth map is not showing.

i followed this tutorial : https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

counties["features"][0]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})
```

Choropleth map using plotly.express and carto base map (no token needed)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: Are you able to produce any plotly figure at all?

Comment: I copied and paster your code and it works well. Perhaps there is any update you need to do on the required libraries ?

Comment: @vestland no just for this example

Comment: @Hugolmn i updated them

Comment: @Yoss Is your code containing anything else than these snippets ?